# Using a Provider in a showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

To use a `Provider` in a `showModalBottomSheet`, I need to wrap my `MaterialApp` with a `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Is there any effect on performance if `MaterialApp` is nested with multiple `ChangeNotifierProviders` which are primarily meant to handle bottom sheets in particular screens? Is there any other efficient way to use a `Provider` in a `showModalBottomSheet`?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Answer (score -1):

It is perfectly fine to add multiple providers or use `MultiProvider` above `MaterialApp`, it's actually the right thing to do for global dependencies.

There is a [documented potential performance hit](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#my-application-throws-a-stackoverflowerror-because-i-have-too-many-providers-what-can-i-do) if you're using `MultiProvider` to nest *a lot* of dependencies. This is less to do with widget tree performance but the hit you're taking with instantiating a lot of widgets at once.

As the documentation explains, there are ways around this including splitting your dependencies up and loading them based on state or simply avoiding `MultiProvider`. Your question specifically asks about wrapping your `MaterialApp` with multiple `ChangeNotifierProvider`s instead of using `MultiProvider` so I think you're good in that regard.

A more thorough explanation to your question is that your `Provider`s need to be ***inserted above a `Navigator`*** for new routes that you push on the stack, either with `Navigator.push`, `showModalBottomSheet`, or by modifying `Navigator.pages` depending on which navigation style your using, to be able to access those `Provider`s through the context.

`MaterialApp` builds your "root" `Navigator` which is why they need to be above `MaterialApp`. If you're using the pattern of nested navigation, something we employee a lot in apps I work on, you'll need to make sure any `Provider`s you want in that particular nested `Navigator` are above that `Navigator`. Besides being able to reuse these "inner journey", you can tailor the dependencies (`Provider`s or other `InheritedWidget`s) needed for these navigation trees, allowing you to only inject what is needed where.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need, and shouldn't, wrap the entire app with your provider just to be able to use it in modals (any). Just use the `.value` constructor of a provider and provide the already created provider to the new widget tree (context) applicable to the modal.

There are several examples of this posted here on SO, as well as examples and explanations of why you shouldn't wrap your entire MaterialApp unnecessarily with a bunch of providers.